# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

This gives me an error here I don't understand why this giving me this error the size of my icons is 300kb.

**main_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@drawable/background"
tools:context="com.example.jaypeetan.mftis.login">

    <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="LOGIN"
    android:id="@+id/button_login"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:background="@color/button_material_dark"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:elegantTextHeight="true"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="SIGN UP"
    android:id="@+id/button_signup"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button_login"
    android:background="@color/button_material_dark"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:elegantTextHeight="true"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:src="@drawable/logo"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button_login" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

**main_menu.java**

```
package com.example.jaypeetan.mftis;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class main_menu extends AppCompatActivity {
    Context context;
    static String a_username;
    static String a_password;
    boolean arduino = true;
    private String m_pass = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);

        ImageView abtn_logout = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn_logout);

        abtn_logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(main_menu.this,login.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
    public void onPreferences(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(main_menu.this,preferences.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void onExit(View view){
        System.exit(1);
    }
    //UNLOCK THE DEVICE
    public void onLock(View view){
        final ImageView access_view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_access);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Enter the Password");
        // Set up the input
        final EditText input = new EditText(this);
        // Specify the type of input expected; this, for example, sets the input as a password, and will mask the text
        input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
        builder.setView(input);
        // Set up the buttons
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int pass) {
                m_pass = input.getText().toString();
                if(arduino==true){
                    if(m_pass.equals(a_password)){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"The Drawer is now Locked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        arduino = false;
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Wrong Password Please try again",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }else{
                    if(m_pass.equals(a_password)){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"The Drawer is now UnLocked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        arduino = true;
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Wrong Password Please try again",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }
}
```

**this is the error**

```
06-05 20:57:38.875 22631-22631/com.example.jaypeetan.mftis E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.example.jaypeetan.mftis, PID: 22631
                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.jaypeetan.mftis/com.example.jaypeetan.mftis.main_menu}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2318)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2396)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                          Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
                                                                             at com.example.jaypeetan.mftis.main_menu.onCreate(main_menu.java:29)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5411)
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2396) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609) 
                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249) 
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106) 
                                                                             at com.example.jaypeetan.mftis.main_menu.onCreate(main_menu.java:29) 
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5411) 
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2396) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609) 
                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
                                                                             at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                                                                             at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:587)
                                                                             at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:422)
                                                                             at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
                                                                             at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2192)
                                                                             at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2075)
                                                                             at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
                                                                             at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:129)
                                                                             at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:119)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249) 
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106) 
                                                                             at com.example.jaypeetan.mftis.main_menu.onCreate(main_menu.java:29) 
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5411) 
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2396) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609) 
                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I think the problem is on my ImageView with iD: image_access
I dont understand why its giving me that error
thanks for the help :)

Comment: Use  android:layout_above="@+id/button_login" > android:layout_above="@id/button_login",  android:layout_below="@+id/button_login" > android:layout_below="@id/button_login" and please post your activity onCreate code

Comment: Post the first few lines of your LogCat, too.

Comment: your logo is vector?

Comment: Done.. i added the main_menu.java and error

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`...  Your image is too large. Consider using an image loading library like Picasso

Comment: is there a way to avoid that aside from using picasso

Answer (score 3):

if your logo icon is vector change your `ImageView`

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo"
    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button_login" />
```

Comment: I dont know if its a vector but the extension is png

Answer (score 2):

Your icon image file is too big, you need to resize it down to a reasonable size.i.e 56x56 or at max 512x512

Use a image software or online image resizing web app to resize your icon.

You can also use [TinyPNG](https://tinypng.com/) to compress your icon image further.

Follow the design guidelines from [official documentation](http://www.androiddocs.com/design/style/iconography.html) from google

[Reference Link](https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/icons.html)